# parsing in a query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this sp. I just found out that M.MDS_FILE column, contains a file name as this:
adlu201008261156_3.zip.  The submission date is embedded in the file name.

How can I pick out this date?  20100826 this portion and use in the sp? that is the date needed to use here:
instead of GETDATE.

```
  SET ANSI_NULLS ON
            GO
            SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
            GO

            ALTER PROC [dbo].[GET_SCHEDULE_SUBMITTED_DETAIL]
            @FACILITYKEY varchar(1000),
            @UNITSTR VARCHAR(100),
            @FromDate datetime,
            @ToDate datetime
            AS
            BEGIN

            SELECT S.FACILITY_KEY, S.PAT_NUMBER, S.A3A_DATE_USER, M.REFERENCE_DATE ,
            RTRIM(P.LAST_NAME) + CASE WHEN RTRIM(P.FIRST_NAME) <> '' THEN ', '
            ELSE ''
            END + RTRIM(P.FIRST_NAME) PATIENT_NAME
            ,CASE WHEN P.NURSING_UNIT is not null THEN P.NURSING_UNIT ELSE '' END NURSING_UNIT
            ,CASE WHEN P.UNIT_CODE is not null THEN P.UNIT_CODE ELSE '' END UNIT_CODE, 'SUBMITTED'  AS ASSESSMENTS
            FROM [OPTC].MDS_M_SCHEDULE S INNER JOIN OPTC.MD3_M_MAST M
            ON S.PAT_NUMBER=M.PAT_NUMBER
            LEFT JOIN OGEN.GEN_M_PATIENT_MAST P ON S.PAT_NUMBER = P.PAT_NUMBER
            WHERE S.PAT_NUMBER=M.PAT_NUMBER AND M.REFERENCE_DATE < GETDATE()
            AND S.A3A_DATE_USER BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate
            AND M.SIGN_DATE IS NOT NULL AND M.MDS_FILE IS NOT NULL AND S.FACILITY_KEY IN (SELECT Value FROM dbo.ListToTable(@FACILITYKEY,','))
            AND ( @UNITSTR IS NULL
            OR @UNITSTR = ''
            OR CHARINDEX(P.UNIT_CODE, @UNITSTR)% 2 = 1 )

            END
```

Comment: How different are other names from `adlu201008261156_3.zip`? Do they all start with `adlu`? Or maybe they all have the date at the same position from the beginning of the name? or maybe from the end? Please be more elaborate so we could find the most appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't mention which database this is, but most have a function for performing a regex match on a string. For instance, Oracle has REGEXP_SUBSTR. Run that on the column, with the proper regex (something like `\d{12}`) and then parse the result as a date.

Edit: And consider changing your schema as posted in the earlier answer - if possible because this won't be super efficient.

Comment: sql server, also the environment is multi machines including legacy systems hence why they pass the zip file name like that.

Answer (score 1):

OMG.

I would STRONGLY SUGGEST you change your schema to include the date you need to track. Intially populate it with dates extracted from the file names, but use the date field when inserting new records from now on. Why?

1. You WILL have mal-formed file names which will hose your logic.
2. You will be extracting the same data again and again for queries - it will be slooow and it makes no sense to do it again and again.
3. That's what databases are good at - don't make it so hard to get at the data you need.